# Change title slug or separator in WordPress

Tags: themes

I have added `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` function in theme setup in my functions.php now it shows the title as:

```
title-WordPress
```

I would like it to be changed as follows:

```
title | WordPress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the title separator, you'll need to use this filter [document_title_separator](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/) which was introduced since WordPress 4.4.0.

Here's how you can customize the separator:

```
apply_filters( 'document_title_separator', 'your_custom_separator' );
function your_custom_separator( $separator ) {

    $separator = '|';

    return $separator;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Updated Answer**

```
add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'your_custom_separator' );
function your_custom_separator( $separator ) {

    $separator = '|';

    return $separator;

}
```

I've tested this with Twenty sixteen theme.[image: See code] [image: See working site]